# Python - Dynamically initialize class based on parameter

Tags: python, localization

The background:

I'm working on a fairly large application that had hardcoded strings throughout it. The time came when the application needed to be localized and translated. At that point, all (or nearly all) hardcoded strings were moved into an appropriately named class with parameters for the strings.

What I need to do:

What I'm attempting to do is have all of these string class objects extend a base class. Inside of that base class, I'm grabbing the OS's default locale and want to load the appropriate localized class in a different folder.

What I have so far:

**Example String Class - file name HeaderStrings.py**

```
class TabLabels(BaseLanguageClass):
    label_one = 'Label 1'
    label_two = 'Label 2'
    label_three = 'Label 3'
```

**BaseLanguageClass**

```
class BaseLanguageClass(object):
    def __init__(self, os_locale=None):
        if os_locale is None:
            os_locale = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
        if os_locale == 'en_US':
            pass  #  Do nothing and just initialize the called class
        else:
            # Gets set to TabLabels
            string_class = str(self.___class__.__name__)

            # Gets set to HeaderStrings
            file_path = str(inspect.getfile(self.__class__)).split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]

            try:
                object_i_want = getattr(__import__("path.to.l10n.classes.%s.%s" % (os_locale, file_path), 
                                                   fromlist=[string_class]), string_class)()
            except:
                pass
```

`object_i_want` correctly gets the localized class that I need. However, I need to be able to return this instead of the actual one called. If the import fails, it just returns the one called. I've tried assigning `object_i_want` to self, but I know that's not going to work but I tried it out of desperation.

If I do:

`var = TabLabels(os_locale='fr').label_one`, stepping through it it correctly gets the French class for `object_i_want`, but var ends up being an instance of the original TabLables instead of fr.TabLabels

What I have is probably extremely hackish and I'm hoping there is a better way to do this without having to refactor close to 2000 files. Any and all assistance is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds as if you're fairly far along, but have you thought about using Python's [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gettext.html) library? It would certainly keep you from having to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: Switching to something like gettext would be optimal in the long run, and I have it on my "nice to have" list to go that route. But unfortunately, the immediate needs of the software outweigh the benefits of dedicating resources to that amount of refactoring.

Comment: Understood.  I figured as much, but thought I'd throw it out there, in case the thought hadn't occurred.  Unfortunately, beyond that, I've got nothing on this one.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing with this, I've determined that the best way to go about this is to use `__new__` to actually retun the class object that I want.

Unfortunately, other colleagues of mine have been referencing the static variables directly instead of creating a new instance of the class (`TabLabels.label_one` vs `TabLabels().label_one`). So a good deal of refactoring appears to be required in the end. Unless someone has a solution to this.

```
class BaseLanguageClass(object):
    def __new__(self, os_locale=None):
        if os_locale is None:
            os_locale = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
        if os_locale == 'en_US':
            return self
        else:
            # Gets set to TabLabels
            string_class = str(self).split('\\')[0].split('.')[-1].split('\'')[0]

            # Gets set to HeaderStrings
            file_path = str(self).split('\\')[0].split('.')[-2]

            try:
                return getattr(__import__("path.to.l10n.classes.%s.%s" % (os_locale, file_path), 
                                               fromlist=[string_class]), string_class)
            except:
                return self
```